# Best power transistor for a high PWM output from ESP32

Tags: transistors, mosfet, infrared, darlington, esp32

I need your advice whether to use a Tip122 Darlington transistor or a BD137 medium-power transistor Or a IRL3705 MOSFET to drive 10 Parallel infrared LEDs.

Each LED has a forward voltage of almost 1.2-1.5 V and takes 40mA of current. This makes the total current required to be 400mA. I am using a 5 V power supply which can give 2 amperes continuous current that I will apply to source/collector.

I will be using an ESP32 to generate 38 kHz pulses to the base/gate of the transistor. Keep in mind that ESP32 can provide 3.3V and very low GPIO source current (some say 12mA and others 40mA max.)

Can you tell me which one will be optimal from my usage?
I will be connecting these LEDs to the source/collector.

As from my research Tip122 may not work properly at 38Khz switching frequency, the BD137 only has a gain of 10 that means that if I am giving 40mA or 12mA of base current I may either get 400mA or 120mA (extra doesn't hurt but having less definitely does).

IRL3705 is expensive and also has Vgs(th) of 2V maximum, meaning that either it may not work correctly or it would have a high Rds(on).

[image]

P.S. You can see the picture attached for 4 of these LEDs and you can imagine the rest of 10 of these. The picture would be same if I am using a n-channel enhancement MOSFET.

Comment: I could be wrong with my research thats why i need your help, kindly point out where did i analyze wrong.

Comment: You can reduce the overall current by 50% using pairs of LEDs in an array of 5P2S

Comment: I understand where you are coming from. But that means a single fault will affect both the LEDs. I am making a permanent setup so i want something that needs minimum maintenance.

Comment: 40% of 40mA is well below max rated current. What maintenance?

Comment: If an led gets broken, that means that two leds will not work at the same time because they are in series.

Comment: WHy should LED get broken. You already have a single point of failure in +5V

Comment: A single point of failure makes it easy to troubleshoot. Anyhow i need to clarify the LEDs application, i am putting these leds on each step of a staircase so there is a fair chance that someone may step on them and break the led.

Comment: I can imagine some other problems with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a small logic-level MOSFET to switch 400mA, eg. [AO3400A](http://aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AO3400A.pdf). The IRL3705 will probably work too, but it is not characterized for 3.3V drive and has a lot more gate charge (more than 10x) so it will switch more slowly.

Comment: it can dissipate a maximum of 1.4 Watts. 1.4 Watts divided by 5V gives 280 mA which is too low for my application.

Comment: Rds(on) with 2.5V drive is less than 0.048 ohms  so it will dissipate less than 0.4 ^2*  0.048 = 8mW. Typically more like 4mW with 3.3V. So it will run *cold*. BTW, 1.4W is not something you should **ever** consider trying with an SOT-23, it will unsolder itself lickety-split and fall on the floor.

Comment: I am a beginner in MOSFETs, i confused its working with that of a bjt.

Comment: As for IRL3705, it has a rise and fall time in nanoseconds so switching 10 times more slowly would still be faster than microseconds. as 1/38000 = 36.315 microseconds,

Comment: The TIP122 Darlington will drop about 0.75V at 400mA typically so it will have to dissipate 300mW. Not enough to require a heatsink, but enough to get noticeably warm and enough that the resistor values need to be adjusted.

Comment: The datasheet rise and fall times are when it is driven with almost **3 amperes** gate current, you are not going to get anything like that with a wimpy MCU GPIO directly driving the gate.

Comment: How about FQP30N06L ?

Comment: Not even as good as the IRL3705. Too big gate charge and only characterized with 5V min drive.

Comment: The other available mosfets in my country is 2n7000 and BS170. Unfortunately, many companies do not ship to our country so it is difficult to find an exact model of the mosfet.

Comment: Iran? Yeah, I guess that's a problem.

Comment: Pakistan, other ways could be if i amplify my signal using a op-amp to 5v or 12v and supply if to the mosfet or i could add a transistor like 2n2222 with the emitter connected to BD139.

Comment: IRL3705 will most likely work. If you're only making one, I say go for it. If it doesn't then add a driver circuit (but I bet it works more than well enough for hobby use). Expect fall times in the 2us range.

Comment: As a last question, what about driving the mosfet with op-amp output attached to the gate?. An op-amp that could deliver 50-100 mA output current.

Comment: Fraught with perils. Often op-amps don't behave nicely when switching.

Comment: can i use TC4424 driver with irl3705?

Comment: Overkill, but yeah, that will work wonderfully.

Comment: hmmm, thinking of the possibilities, a logic level converter can also do the job if we connect 5v output of the converter to mosfet gate. Specifically the one incorporating a BSS138 mosfet like sparkfun.

Answer (score 2):

This is best dealt with a N channel enhancement mode mosfet.
The current draw from the GPIO pin on the ESP32 will be much lower and the on/off of the transistor will be better/faster.

380mA is not that much in the world of most mosfets.  A quick digikey search finds a 3.2A part in a SOT-23 package for $0.43/each.  NTR4170NT1G.  With 3.3V on the gate it'll have about 55mΩ Rds-on or about 8mW of dissipation.

Comment: Digikey, sparkfun, amazon and ebay doesnt ship to our country.

Comment: @HermanZahid Good point.  You'll have to work with suppliers that work with your country. But you should be able to do a similar search for small mosfets and find a suitable part.

Comment: currently discussing it with the Sphero Pefhany (The one who answered above), we are looking for other ways.